# blockhash refactoring, if hashes are relative to latest block, are all stored in contract?

Tags: contract-development

The [blockhash refactoring EIP](http://swende.se/blog/Blockhash-Refactor.html) included in Constantinople expands the range of blocks that can be accessed with `blockhash()`. Besides the last 256 blocks, 256 multiples of 256^1, and 256 multiples of 256^2 can also be accessed. The EIP also stores the blockhashes to a contract (was my impression). Since the range of blockhashes are from the latest block, does that mean that depending on the refence frame, all blockhashes will be available? For example, that over 256 blocks, the 256s multiples of 256^1 will provide every single block within that range (up to 256^2 blocks)? Is yes, why not just allow access to all those blocks from any reference frame?